# integrate the following expression

Tags: integration

Question:
integrate $\sqrt{t}$

My answer:
$t^{\frac{1}{2}} = \dfrac{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}} +c$

correct answer:
$\frac{2}{3}.t^{\frac{3}{2}} +c$

what am I doing wrong? thank's

Comment: Both are the same, just written differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int \sqrt{t} = \int t^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}} + C = \frac{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} + C$$

where $C \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

This is because
$$ \frac{1}{3/2} = \frac{2}{3}, $$
and
$$ t^{3/2} = t^{1.5}. $$
You have the correct answer, but in a slightly different form.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one get the following hint which you can prove applying the chain rule:

$$\int f'(x)\cdot e^{f(x)}dx=e^{f(x)}+C$$

Comment: I think you are answering a different question DON! but +1 anyway

Comment: I could swear over my cousin's girlfriend's grandaunt's grave that there was an additional question about how to integrate $\;e^{5x}/5\;$, but since one can edit without showing within five minutes after posting then...

Comment: it feels good to be a don, right?

Comment: yeah you are right but then I realize that I wrote the answer instead of the question. thank's thou

Comment: I knew I'm not mad! Thanks @CashVai